# forms.ModelForm does not save ManyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am working with forms (`forms.ModelForm`) and I have some small inconvenient when I create my form based in the models. My situation such as follow in my `models.py` file:

I have the `CorporalSegment` model:

```
class CorporalSegment(models.Model):
    SEGMENTO_HOMBRO = 'Hombro'
    SEGMENTO_CODO = 'Codo'
    SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO = 'Antebrazo'
    SEGMENTO_MANO = 'Mano'

    SEGMENT_CHOICES = (
        (SEGMENTO_HOMBRO, u'Hombro'),
        (SEGMENTO_CODO, u'Codo'),
        (SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO, u'Antebrazo'),
        (SEGMENTO_MANO, u'Mano'),
    )

    corporal_segment = models.CharField(
        max_length=12,
        choices=SEGMENT_CHOICES,
        blank=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Segmentos Corporales'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.corporal_segment
```

I have the `Movement` model

```
class Movements(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Movimiento'
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Movimientos'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

And I have the `Metric` model

```
class Metrics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Nombre'
    )
    value = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits = 5,
        decimal_places = 3,
        verbose_name = 'Valor',
        null = True,
        blank = True
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Métrica'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{},{}".format(self.name, self.value)
```

My purpose is that in one form, I can save multiple values (instances) of `CorporalSegment`, `Movement` and `Metric` models, and due to this, I have the `PatientMonitoring` model of this way:

```
class PatientMonitoring(models.Model):

    patient = models.ForeignKey(...)
    medical = models.ForeignKey(...)

    # My fields pointing to my previous models with many to many relationship
    corporal_segment = models.ManyToManyField(CorporalSegment, verbose_name='Segmentos Corporales')
    movement = models.ManyToManyField(Movements, verbose_name='Movimientos')
    metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Metrics, verbose_name='Métricas', )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Monitoreo del paciente'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.patient
```

My `views.py` file

```
class PatientMonitoringCreate(CreateView):
    model = PatientMonitoring
    form_class = PatientMonitoringForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patientmonitoring:list')

class PatientMonitoringUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = PatientMonitoring
    form_class = PatientMonitoringForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patientmonitoring:list')
```

My `forms.py` is of this way:

```
from django import forms

from .models import PatientMonitoring

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class PatientMonitoringForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PatientMonitoringForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', u'Save'))

    # I think so that here is my problem ...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        patient_monitoring = super(PatientMonitoringForm, self).save(commit=False)
        patient = self.cleaned_data['patient']

        if commit:
            patient_monitoring.save()
        return patient_monitoring

    class Meta:
        model = PatientMonitoring
        fields = ['patient', 'medical','corporal_segment','movement','metrics']
```

And my template `patientmonitoring_form.html` is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Crear Registro de Monitoreo de Paciente{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div>
    {% crispy form %}
    {% csrf_token %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I want save a `PatientMonitoring` instance in their respective form, the `corporal_segment` (Segmentos Corporales) `movement` (Movimientos) and `metrics` (Metricas) fields in the form, their values are not saved in the form (in squares red), but the another fields are saved (not red squared)

[image]

This behavior is strange for me, because via Django admin form, is possible save a `PatientMonitoring` instance with all their attributes.

What thing can I will be ignoring in the moment of save in my form `save` method in my `PatientMonitoringForm` in `forms.py` file?

Answer (score 7):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

When using commit=False, you have to call save_m2m()

m2m relationships require the parent object to be saved first, which you are not doing by using commit=False.