# Django m2m not saves in m2m_changed signal

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have a model **Location** with m2m relation with **Place** and **School**

Each time **places** field is changed I want to set all existing **schools** to **Location**

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

class Location(model.Model):

    places = models.ManyToManyField(Place, related_name='locations')

    schools = models.ManyToManyField(School, related_name='locations')


def places_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    instance.schools = School.objects.all()

    print(instance.schools.all())

m2m_changed.connect(places_changed, sender=Location.places.through)
```

> print(instance.schools.all())  - prints all school objects, but nothing saved - db is empty.

Please help) Thx for advices!

Comment: try to look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448564/forms-modelform-does-not-save-manytomany-fields/38495003#38495003

Comment: @Compadre It did not help(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Getting m2m related objects in signals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528922/django-getting-m2m-related-objects-in-signals)